# Primefaces datatable filter doesn't work

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable

I must do something fundamentally wrong, I stripped down the code to the bare minimum with a data table and enabling one column filter and a globe filter.

The funny thing is that the example code from Primefaces works. The only difference to my code should be that it gathers data from a DB rather than generating it in the bean.

I have no more clues why my example doesn't do anything when I type something in the filter would be appreciate any ideas here.

My xhtml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">All Projects</ui:define>    

    <ui:define name="content">


        <p:dataTable var="project" value="#{projectController.allProjects}" widgetVar="projectTable" filteredValue="#{projectController.filteredProjects}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>  
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('projectTable').filter()" style="width:150px" />  
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Name" filterBy="#{project.name}">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.name}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Priority">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.priority}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Exit">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.exitCriteria}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>      

    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My Bean:

```
    package com.apa.projectd.common;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import com.habony.common.Loggable;
    import com.habony.projectd.ejbs.ProjectEJB;
    import com.habony.projectd.enteties.Project;

    @ManagedBean(name="projectController")
    @SessionScoped
    @Loggable
    public class ProjectController implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 8345760187637787728L;

@Inject
private ProjectEJB projectEJB;

private List<Project> filteredProjects;
private List<Project> allProjects;

@PostConstruct
public void loadAllProjects(){
    allProjects =  projectEJB.getAllProjects();
}

//
// Getters and Setters
//
public List<Project> getFilteredProjects() {
    return filteredProjects;
}

public void setFilteredProjects(List<Project> filteredProjects) {
    this.filteredProjects = filteredProjects;
}

public void setAllProjects(List<Project> allProjects) {
    this.allProjects = allProjects;
}

public List<Project> getAllProjects(){
    return allProjects;
}
```

}

Comment: Is it even showing any data? or is it just that the filter isn't working?

Comment: Showing the data works fine.

Comment: The problem is in the column or the global filter?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The filters features of p:dataTable need to be wrapped in `<h:form>` tags for work fine. The code xhtml modified would:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="layout.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">All Projects</ui:define>    

    <ui:define name="content">
       <h:form>
           <p:dataTable var="project" value="#{projectController.allProjects}" widgetVar="projectTable" filteredValue="#{projectController.filteredProjects}">

              <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>  
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('projectTable').filter()" style="width:150px" />  
                 </p:outputPanel>
              </f:facet>

              <p:column headerText="Name" filterBy="#{project.name}">
                 <h:outputText value="#{project.name}" />
              </p:column>

              <p:column headerText="Priority">
                 <h:outputText value="#{project.priority}" />
              </p:column>

             <p:column headerText="Exit">
                 <h:outputText value="#{project.exitCriteria}" />
             </p:column>

          </p:dataTable>      
      </h:form>
   </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: This works while you are not using pagination and lazy. The moment I started to use lazy and pagination the filter crash. No errors, but simply It doesn't work!

Comment: @MadMad666, the question is specifically about filter which does not work. Not pagination, or lazy load.

Answer (score 4):

Please see lazy property this may be that your data not filter.

`lazy="true"` change `lazy=false`

Comment: Works fine to me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue with sorting and filtering. 

Answer (score 1):

finally I figured out that when you use Lazy the filtered data is not stored in other variable as in non lazy implementation, everytime you call a filter the load method is executed, so I had to put the filters also in my Load, also the sorting this is the way when using Lazy.

My mistake !

Comment: The code above does not use lazy, so this answer is not valid for this question

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize **filtredProjects** with the same data that contains the ArrayList **allProjects**  like this:

```
@PostConstruct
public void loadAllProjects(){
allProjects =  projectEJB.getAllProjects();
filtredProjects = projectEJB.getAllProjects();
}
```

Comment: finally I figured out that when you use Lazy the filtered data is not stored in other variable as in non lazy implementation, everytime you call a filter the load method is executed, so I had to put the filters also in my Load, also the sorting this is the way when using Lazy. 

My mistake !

Answer (score -1):

Do not use lazy loading when filtering and/or sorting