# Filter and paging in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am creating a dataTable that shows task. I only want to have 8 tasks in each page and also I want to filter the tasks shown by finished and not finished.

I have implemented these two things and both of them work separated, but when I join them an exception is thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest

Here is the code of the dataTable:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/templates/template-usuario.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="cuerpo">
        <h:form id="formTareas">
            <p:dataTable id="tablaTareas" var="tarea" value="#{controller.tasks}"
                border="1" selection="#{controller.selectedTasks}"
                widgetVar="tasksTable" rowKey="#{tarea.id}" rows="8"
                paginator="true">

                <p:column selectionMode="multiple"
                    style="width:16px;text-align:center" />
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.titulo}</f:facet>#{tarea.title}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.comentario}</f:facet>#{tarea.comments}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.fechaCreacion}</f:facet>#{tarea.created}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.fechaPlanificacion}</f:facet>#{tarea.planned}</p:column>


                <p:column filterBy="#{tarea.finished==null}"
                    headerText="#{msgs.fechaFinalizacion}" filterMatchMode="equals">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneButton onchange="PF('tasksTable').filter()">
                            <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.Boolean" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Not Finished" itemValue="true" />
                        </p:selectOneButton>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{tarea.finished}" />
                </p:column>


                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.fechaFinalizacion}</f:facet>#{tarea.finished}</p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msgs.categoria}</f:facet>#{tarea.categoryId}</p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I think that you are wrong in your `filterBy="#{tarea.finished==null}"` try to remove it and see what's happening

Comment: @YagamiLight In order to know whether a task is finished or not I have to check if its finish date is null or not. However the program filters the tasks in the right way. The problem arrives when I try to change between the different pages of the table with one filter activated.

Comment: the problem is i've never see a filter with null value this is why i told you to try remove and see what's happening, and even if it's the problem i will give an alternative solution

Comment: @YagamiLight How can I filter the tasks by terminated and not terminated without checking if the value of finished (it is of type date) is null?

Comment: you can replace a null value by a character value like not rensigned or something like this , read an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293134/primefaces-datatable-filter-doesnt-work

Comment: a filter is working based on the character varing filter not null or not

Comment: @YagamiLight but when that expression is evaluated it produces a boolean, so the value of filterBy would be true or false. But that's not the problem, if I only filter the values everything is right. The problem arrives when I add the paging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137372/discussion-between-yagami-light-and-ronce96).