# Datatable Filter JSF 2.4 with PrimeFaces Problem

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I'm trying to add a filter in my datatable, but it's not working. I also tried with global filter but the result was the same. I need my datable get filtered by this 2 basic columns (nucleo and localizacao).

Below my Bean and also the reportes.xhtml

#reportes.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head>

    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="500; url=reportes.xhtml"></meta>

    <title>Reportes Pendentes</title>

    <link rel='shortcut icon' href="resources/images/notepad.ico" />

</h:head>
<h:body>



    <style type="text/css">
.vermelho {
    background-color: #FF6347;
}

.azul {
    background-color: #BFEFFF;
}

</style>
    <table id="tabelaCabecalhoInicio" width="100%">
        <td><p:graphicImage id="teste1"
                style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;"
                value="/resources/images/schmersal1.png" height="95px" width="264px"
                styleClass="teste" /></td>

        <td style="text-align: rigth"><h1>Reportes Schmersal</h1></td>

    </table>


    <p:panel id="tabela">
        <f:facet name="header" style="text-align:center" width="10"> Reportes Pendentes </f:facet>


        

        <p:dataTable id="teste" var="reporte"
            value="#{reporteBean.listaReportes}" widgetVar="reportesTable"
            paginator="false" resizableColumns="true" scrollable="true"
            scrollWidth="95%" scrollHeight="400"
            rowStyleClass="#{reporte.erro ? 'vermelho' : 'azul'}"
            sortBy="#{reporte.erro}" filteredValue="#{reporteBean.listaReportes}" >

            <p:column width="15">
                <f:facet name="header">#</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;text-align:left">#{rowCounter.row} </h:form>
            </p:column>


            <p:column width="80">
                <f:facet name="header">Ignorar</f:facet>
                <p:commandLink style="background-color:#2E366A;color:white"
                    value="Ignorar" type="button"
                    action="#{reporteBean.ignorarReporte(reporte)}" immediate="true"
                    onclick="window.location.reload()" />
            </p:column>


            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.id}" width="45">
                <f:facet name="header">Op</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:11px;text-align:left">#{reporte.ordemProducao.id}</h:form>

            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.codItem}" width="100">
                <f:facet name="header">Item</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:11px;text-align:left">#{reporte.ordemProducao.codItem}</h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.descItem}" width="130">
                <f:facet name="header">Descrição </f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:10px">#{reporte.ordemProducao.descItem}</h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.qtde}" width="52">
                <f:facet name="header">Qtd</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:15px;text-align:center">#{reporte.qtde}</h:form>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.localizacao}" width="100" filterBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.localizacao}">
                <f:facet name="header">Localização </f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px">#{reporte.ordemProducao.localizacao}</h:form>
            </p:column>
            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.deposito}" width="80">
                <f:facet name="header">Depósito </f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px">#{reporte.ordemProducao.deposito}</h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                sortBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.complementoReportes.planejador}"
                width="100">
                <f:facet name="header">Planejador </f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px">#{reporte.ordemProducao.complementoReportes.planejador}</h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column
                sortBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.complementoReportes.nucleo}" filterBy="#{reporte.ordemProducao.localizacao}"
                width="100" filterMatchMode="exact" >
                <f:facet name="header">Nucleo </f:facet>

                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px">#{reporte.ordemProducao.complementoReportes.nucleo}</h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.operacao.centroCusto.id}"
                paginator="false" width="50">
                <f:facet name="header">CC</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;text-align:left">#{reporte.operacao.centroCusto.id} </h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.operacao.centroCusto.descricao}"
                paginator="false" width="150">
                <f:facet name="header">Centro Custo</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;text-align:left">#{reporte.operacao.centroCusto.descricao} </h:form>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.operador.nome}" paginator="false"
                width="230">
                <f:facet name="header">Operador</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;text-align:left">#{reporte.operador.nome} </h:form>
            </p:column>

    

            <p:column sortBy="#{reporte.dthrInclusao}" width="96">
                <f:facet name="header">Inclusão</f:facet>
                <h:form style="text-align:center;font-size:11px">#{reporte.dthrInclusao}</h:form>
            </p:column>

    



        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>






    <p:panel>

        <p:column>
            <h:form style="margin:center">
                <p:clock pattern="dd/MM/yyyy -  HH:mm:ss" />
            </h:form>
        </p:column>
    </p:panel>


    <h:form id="form">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">




        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>



</h:body>
</html>
```

#ReporteBean

```
package br.com.schmersal.reportes.bean;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;

import br.com.schmersal.reportes.dao.ReporteDao;
import br.com.schmersal.svm.apontatouch.hibernate.HibernateUtilSQL;
import br.com.schmersal.svm.apontatouch.modelo.Reporte;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "reporteBean")
public class ReporteBean implements Serializable {

    private List<Reporte> listaReportes = new ArrayList<Reporte>();
    private List<Reporte> listaReportesN1 = new ArrayList<Reporte>();
    private List<Reporte> listaFiltro;
    private ReporteDao dao;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginBean}")
    private LoginBean login;

    // public ReporteBean(){
    //
    // System.out.println("erro");
    //
    // }

    public ReporteBean() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        if (this.login != null && this.login.getOperador() != null && this.login.getOperador().getPaginaReportes()) {
            dao = new ReporteDao(new HibernateUtilSQL());
            try {
                listaReportes = dao.getLista(null);

            } catch (ObjectNotFoundException e) {
                try {
                    atualizaPlanejadoresItens();
                    try {
                        listaReportes = dao.getLista(null);
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } 
            
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public void busca(Long idCentroCusto) {
        dao = new ReporteDao(new HibernateUtilSQL());
        try {
            listaFiltro = dao.getLista(idCentroCusto);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List<Reporte> getListaReportes() throws Exception {

        // TODO tratar erro ao bater no brz-app27 e mudar local da chamada

        if (listaReportes == null) {

            try {
                atualizaPlanejadoresItens();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return listaReportes;
    }
    
    public List<Reporte> getListaReportesN1() throws Exception {

        
        dao.getListaN1(1);

        if (listaReportes == null) {

            try {
                atualizaPlanejadoresItens();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return listaReportes;
    }

    public void setListaReportes(List<Reporte> listaReportes) {
        this.listaReportes = listaReportes;
    }
    //
    // public void ignorarReporte(Repo){
    //
    // ReporteDaoTeste dao = new ReporteDaoTeste(new HibernateUtilSQL());
    // reporte.setIgnorar(true);
    // dao.update(reporte);
    //
    // }

    public void limpar() {

        try {
            listaReportes = dao.getLista(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void ignorarReporte(Reporte reporte) {

        reporte.setIgnorar(true);
        reporte.setDthrUltimaTentativa(new LocalDateTime());
        reporte.setOperadorIgnorar(login.getOperador());
        try {
            dao.update(reporte);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void atualizaPlanejadoresItens() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader readerChamada;
        String line;
        StringBuffer responseContentChamada = new StringBuffer();

        String urlFinal = "http://brz-ti27:8585/telaReportes/integraCompleta";
        // System.out.println(urlFinal);

        URL urlConsulta = new URL(urlFinal);

        HttpURLConnection conexaoConsulta = (HttpURLConnection) urlConsulta.openConnection();

        conexaoConsulta.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conexaoConsulta.setConnectTimeout(50000);
        conexaoConsulta.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
        conexaoConsulta.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conexaoConsulta.setDoOutput(true);
        conexaoConsulta.setDoInput(true);

        int status = conexaoConsulta.getResponseCode();

        if (status == 401) {
            // lançar excecao
        }

        if (status > 299) {
            readerChamada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexaoConsulta.getErrorStream()));
            while ((line = readerChamada.readLine()) != null) {
                responseContentChamada.append(line);
            }

            // readerChamada.close();
        } else {
            readerChamada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexaoConsulta.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = readerChamada.readLine()) != null) {
                responseContentChamada.append(line);
            }

            // readerChamada.close();
        }

        /*
         * GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder(); Gson gson =
         * gsonBuilder.create(); JSONObject jsonObject = new
         * JSONObject(responseContentChamada.toString());
         * 
         * Object fromJson = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), Object.class);
         * 
         * // System.out.println(jsonObject);
         * 
         * System.out.println(fromJson);
         */
    }

    public LoginBean getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(LoginBean login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public List<Reporte> getListaFiltro() {
        return listaFiltro;
    }

    public void setListaFiltro(List<Reporte> listaFiltro) {
        this.listaFiltro = listaFiltro;
    }

    public ReporteDao getDao() {
        return dao;
    }

    public void setDao(ReporteDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void setListaReportesN1(List<Reporte> listaReportesN1) {
        this.listaReportesN1 = listaReportesN1;
    }
    
    

}
```

I was just expecting to have the values filtered by nucleo or by localizacao

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What else exactly would be interesting to add here?

Comment: PrimeFaces version for example. One obvious error I see is that you should wrap your data table in a form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Primefaces datatable filter doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293134/primefaces-datatable-filter-doesnt-work)

Comment: I just tried with h:form tag, but it still didn't work ;( . 
The primefaces version is 5.0